# Delphi 2007 Adoquery Parameters not working

Tags: sql, delphi

```
   ADOQuerySelect.Close;
    ADOQuerySelect.SQL.Add(' AND (дата_заказа between #'+dat+'# and #'+da+'#)');
    if ComboBox6.Text <> '' then
    begin
    ADOQuerySelect.Parameters.ParamByName('Name').Value := ComboBox6.Text ;
      ADOQuerySelect.SQL.Add(' AND (Наименование = :Name)');
    end;
ADOQuerySelect.Open;
```

I use Delphi 2007, MS Access. And i dont now how work with parameters. On this code, i have error: parameter Name not found. I tried many other variants of code, but they all not working. I add parameter Name via GUI with datatype ftstring;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the object inspector ADOQuerySelect should have 'Name' among list of parameters.

You can also use the following code to create the parameter 'Name':

```
with ADOQuerySelect.Parameters.AddParameter do
begin
  Name := 'Name';
  DataType := ftString;
end;
```

Comment: it is, in object inspector

Comment: And is the 'name' in the SQL table?

Comment: The following code for table TAB and one parameter name is working:                                         ADOQuerySelect.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO TAB ( name ) ');
      ADOQuerySelect.SQL.Add(' VALUES (:name) ');
      ADOQuerySelect.Parameters.ParamByName('Name').Value := ComboBox6.Text ;
      try
        ADOQuerySelect.ExecSQL;

Answer (score 3):

Changing SQL in your code clears the existing parameters, so there's no parameter called 'Name' at the time you try to set its value. You then create the `Name` parameter, but it's too late.

Change the order of your statements:

```
ADOQuerySelect.Close;
ADOQuerySelect.SQL.Add(' AND (дата_заказа between #'+dat+'# and #'+da+'#)');
if ComboBox6.Text <> '' then
begin
  ADOQuerySelect.SQL.Add(' AND (Наименование = :Name)');
  ADOQuerySelect.Parameters.ParamByName('Name').Value := ComboBox6.Text ;
end;
ADOQuerySelect.Open;
```

You should be using parameters for *all* your replacements, BTW. Let the database driver handle conversions and date formats and quoting values and all of that for you.